# javascript Focusing does not function when coming from another application

Tags: javascript

I launched an URL which allows me to open a window from an application to another. So, it opens a window which opens another window on that by a js code which started by: (function(glob))

On this window, I can click on a button which must put me on the first window but it did not do that. After clicking on that button the following code is executed:

```
function _giveFocusToMainpage() {
    if (window.opener.name === 'mainpage') {
        var goBack = window.open('', 'mainpage');

        // On lui donne le focus
        goBack.focus();
    } 
}
```

But the variable goBack is undefined, so it did not enter the if condition. And, we can notice that the first window is still here. Also, I checked the value of window.opener.name and it is "".

If I launch the application not from outsite but from the same application, this functionnality does the stuff and entered the if condition. So, finally I reach the first window.

Can you help me in order to debug that please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is the opened application from the same domain as the opener?  If not, this isn't likely to work because potential CORS exploits like this have to be locked down.